# Как изменить разрешение картинке в контроллере? ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

В контроллер заходит файл-картинка. Сигнатура контроллера

```
[HttpPost("add-img/{IdSection}/{idArticle}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddImageForArticle(List<IFormFile> file, string IdSection, string idArticle)
```

Все успешно заходит и сохраняет в базу. Только вот нужно изменить размер изображение и что не мало важно пропорционально. Т.е. изменить максимальную ширину(905px) и автоматом подогнать высоту. Может есть какие-то библиотеки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать следующим образом: открываем картинку как массив байт и там уже задаем новые размеры:

```
byte[] imageBytes;    

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
{
    using (Image img = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        int h = 100;
        int w = 100;

        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img, new Size(w,h)))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                b.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                imageBytes = ms2.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }                        
}
```

Что бы изменять картинку пропорционально, достаточно подключит логику.
К примеру была картинка 1920x1080, высчитываем сколько будет 1% от ширины: `1920 / 100 = 19,2`. Теперь узнаем на сколько процентов уменьшилась ширина `(1920 - 905) / 19,2 = 52,86%` Значит уменьшим высоту на столько процентов: `1080 / 100 * 52,86 = 571`. Вписываем эти размеры вместо `int h` и `int w` и все готово.

Comment: Хорошо бы уточнить, что такое `Image` и `Bitmap`, из какой библиотеки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `using System.Drawing;`

Comment: А как вы открываете картинку как массив байт. Вот в моем примере она приходит в переменную file[0]

Comment: Такая строка дает ошибку byte[] imageBytes = file[0];